# TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when importing a function from a different folder in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-class

I have a class in code.py in a folder(cog) that looks like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Class(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self):
        # Basic initialisation

    @commands.command()
    async def func(self, ctx = commands.Context):
        # Code for the command
```

When I try to import it (to add it to a scheduler using `APScheduler`) like the following:

```py
from folder import code

async def schedule_func():
    func_class = code.Class()
    await func_class.func()
```

I get the following error:

```
File "bot/main.py", line 45, in schedule_meme
     await func_class.func()
File "/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in __call__
     return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I looked up everywhere and double-checked that I was initialising the class first but still I can't get past the error.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what happened here, it is reproducible and it worked when I  simply passed ctx as a random value.

```py
await func_class.func(commands.Context) #if you need to use it, or just 1 or any literal
```

edit: the `commands.command()` decorator seems to be the problem here, removing it made it run without a parameter, my guess is that the decorator made ctx a required argument, if you don't want to use ctx. you can change the decorator to `@commands.command(pass_context=False)` and it will run fine without any parameters

Comment: I am sorry but this didn't worked for me. It again returned the same error i.e `send() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: Can you try removing the `commands.command` decorator, just for debugging